# How to receive/create a dynamic identifier to pay a user using php and stripe?

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I'm working on a project where I'll fetch items from a database for different users and display them my their own page. At the minute their items are got by getting the username query string from the url then selecting the data relating to that username. The problem I'm having is the actual payment bit. Stripe payment itself isn't' the problem, it's pointing that payment to the right direction. Stripe uses a stripe user ID to tell where the payment should go, that stripeUserID is stored in the database and linked to their own user ID.

At the minute it goes users item page>get items page> users item page(populated) and when another person buys something here it then goes to the payment php file. I could get an identifier for a user by either storing their username or userid in a session variable or even using the current query string stored in a session variable, the problem here is if they loaded another users item page at the same time, the variables would be overwritten sending the payment to the wrong location. Another idea was to get the userid from the getitems page and store it in a form on the items page then post it in a hidden input field, however, this could be changed by the user if they knew how. I could put some validation in the payment php file to check if the posted userid is correct but what could I even compare it to to check? I'm confused as to how I actually make a secure dynamic identifier which can be sent from different pages and not be changed.

Comment: no code no help!  What have you tried?  What is the issue you're having with your current code?

Comment: so the customer is buying a product which has an id, so when they submit the payment information they should specify the product they want to buy. Then your code can look up the stripe user id, amount etc based on that product

Comment: to jeff - The user ID to get paid is stored in a session variable. So if they open one item page then a second item page and buy something from the first, the payment will go to the second page's user instead.

Comment: Matthew - I just realised I'm being a bit dumb. Although the user could change the hidden form value, it would only affect them, only they would be able to pay a different user than which is intended so I suppose it doesn't really matter? What I'm doing now is passing the product ID in a hidden form input and then getting the info from the payment file. Does that sound correct?

Comment: yep that sounds correct, worst case they'd pay a different user but its not like they would be receiving goods they didn't pay for since they'd be getting exactly the product they said they wanted.